# How to center label vertically on input inside a table?

Tags: css

Is there a way to vertically center this label inside the input? I did try the table/table-cell approach, but it didn't work here.

html:

```
<table class="header-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-2">
        <label>asdf</label>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.header-table .column-2 label {
  position: absolute;
}

.header-table .column-2 input {
  height: 32px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/aj6eb2v6/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.header-table .column-2 {
    position: relative;
}

.header-table .column-2 label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header-table .column-2 input {
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!-- placeholder vertical centered -->
<table class="header-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-2">
        <label>asdf</label>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Offsetting the label vertically using `transform` and `top`. Doing it this way will automatically scale based on the size of the element. No need to guess offsets etc. :)

Well supported in browsers too - http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Works! Actually, I can use simply `transform: translateY(50%);` without the `top:50%` :)

Comment: Updated my answer based off your feedback so it's cleaner :)

Comment: Actually, again, this approach worked for this snipped, but in the project I needed the approach using top+transform here. Not sure why (it's a huge code).

Comment: Ahhh okay, I've added the `top` back in incase others need it

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute positioning is not currently relative to the cell it is inside.

```css
.header-table .column-2{
  position:relative;
}
.header-table .column-2 label {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-11px;
  height:100%;
}

.header-table .column-2 input {
  height: 32px;
  line-height:32px;
}
```

```html
<!-- placeholder vertical centered -->
<table class="header-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-2">
        <label>asdf</label>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the height of the container is `32px`, you can give a `32px` line-height to the label. This might be the easy trick as you don't have to worry about browser support.

See,

```css
.header-table .column-2 label {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.header-table .column-2 input {
  height: 32px;
}

td.column-2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- placeholder vertical centered -->
<table class="header-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-2">
        <label>asdf</label>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```